# Can I approximate a measurable set with an open set for integration purposes?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have a Lebesgue measurable function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $X\subset\mathbb{R}$. Is there an open set $X^O$ such that 
\begin{equation*}
\int_X f=\int_{X^O} f
\end{equation*}
and $X^O$ is very similar to $X$ in some sense?

Comment: $X$ may not have an open subset; do you want to allow $f$ to be extended to a larger domain? If so, and $X$ is measurable then the answer to your question taken literally is yes, because you can extend $f$ to $\mathbb R$ so that $\int_{\mathbb R} f > \int_X f$, and then use intermediate value theorem on the family of open intervals $(-a, a)$ for $a \in \mathbb R^{\ge 0}$ (if $\mathbb R-X$ has measure zero, just take $X^O=\mathbb R$). But morally, I'm thinking it's likely what you want is more like an open set $X^O$ that differs from $X$ on a set of measure zero, in which case the answer is no.